# How to use let in an HTML template?

Tags: html, angular, let

I'm trying to do something which should be simple:
I would like to execute a function in an *ngFor. The function returns an object. I would like to set the object in a kind of "let" statement, so I can use its property in the HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let productGroup of getproductGroupBySomeVariable(variable)">
            <!-- This is where I need to set a variable with the output of 
             the getProductBySomeProperty function-->
      <div *ngLet="'{{getProductBySomeProperty(productGroup.someproperty)}}' 
              as  myVar" class="ui-g">
              <!-- Here I want to use and display the properties of the 
                object created by the function above-->
            <span>{{myVar.property1}} </span>
            <span>{{myVar.property2}} </span> etc....
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You wouldn't want to use a function like that in template. It will be fired on each change detection.

Comment: @AJT_82 - You are right - I gathered it all arranged as data-structure in the componenet

Answer (score 6):

You can create a directive for this, and use it this way:

**Directive**

```js
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

interface ILetContext<T> {
    ngLet: T;
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngLet]'
})
export class LetDirective<T> {
    private context: ILetContext<T> = { ngLet: undefined };

    constructor(viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, templateRef: TemplateRef<ILetContext<T>>) {
        viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(templateRef, this.context);
    }

    @Input()
    private set ngLet(value: T) {
        this.context.ngLet = value;
    }
}
```

**Html**

```
<ng-container *ngLet="getproductGroupBySomeVariable(variable) as productGroup;"></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to mention an alternative solution that works really well:

- single subscription
- works with falsy values
- is strongly typed

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="{ user: user | async } as context"> <!-- always true -->
    {{ context.user }}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to hide things in the template when the data is falsy. You've commented that in this case user observable is always true... this is something you're doing in the typescript code, is that correct? If so, I think a directive that doesn't depend on the typescript code worth the extra work to have your own directive.

Comment: you can always check `context.user == null` as it will be `null` when its falsy or loading

Comment: This is working for the first value from Observable stream, not for the others. I've tried this for my `isLoading` flag and first `true` value is successfully received, but then `false` is never noticed by this construction.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-let

source code of the directive: https://github.com/nigrosimone/ng-let/blob/main/projects/ng-let/src/lib/ng-let.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

interface NgLetContext<T> {
    ngLet: T;
    $implicit: T;
}

@Directive({
    // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
    selector: '[ngLet]'
})
export class NgLetDirective<T> {

    private context: NgLetContext<T | null> = { ngLet: null, $implicit: null };
    private hasView: boolean = false;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<NgLetContext<T>>) { }

    @Input()
    set ngLet(value: T) {
        this.context.$implicit = this.context.ngLet = value;
        if (!this.hasView) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, this.context);
            this.hasView = true;
        }
    }

    /** @internal */
    public static ngLetUseIfTypeGuard: void;

    /**
     * Assert the correct type of the expression bound to the `NgLet` input within the template.
     *
     * The presence of this static field is a signal to the Ivy template type check compiler that
     * when the `NgLet` structural directive renders its template, the type of the expression bound
     * to `NgLet` should be narrowed in some way. For `NgLet`, the binding expression itself is used to
     * narrow its type, which allows the strictNullChecks feature of TypeScript to work with `NgLet`.
     */
    static ngTemplateGuard_ngLet: 'binding';

    /**
     * Asserts the correct type of the context for the template that `NgLet` will render.
     *
     * The presence of this method is a signal to the Ivy template type-check compiler that the
     * `NgLet` structural directive renders its template with a specific context type.
     */
    static ngTemplateContextGuard<T>(dir: NgLetDirective<T>, ctx: any): ctx is NgLetContext<Exclude<T, false | 0 | '' | null | undefined>> {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { defer, Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngLet="timer$ | async as time"> <!-- single subscription -->
    <div>
      1: {{ time }}
    </div>
    <div>
      2: {{ time }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  timer$: Observable<number> = defer(() => timer(3000, 1000));
}
```